# Modifying number of instructions into one

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

Currently my program uses three lines

```
    add    ax, Records[bx+4]
    add    ax, Records[bx+6]
    add    ax, Records[bx+8]
```

I was wondering can I modify the program to use a single instruction in a loop in place of the 3 instructions, as I will change both bx and the constant, I am unable to convert it into a single instruction.

Comment: Yes, you can do that in a loop with an `add bx,2` increment, but setting up a loop counter would take an instruction, and so would the loop branch, so for only 3 ADD instructions it's best to fully unroll (aka peel) the loop.  You're correct that there's no single instruction for this, not even with SSE2, AVX2, or AVX-512 SIMD.  (The existing horizontal-add SIMD instructions only add pairs, and are slow anyway.)

Comment: `lodsw; add bx, ax` is an option, but that too takes 2 instructions per iteration.

Comment: On x64 one can perform the whole sequence by multiplying uint64_t from `Records[bx + 4]` by 0x000100010001ull, assuming that one can access the fourth element as well.

Comment: Are you writing general x86 assembly code, or optimizing specifically for the 8088/8086 processor? *Very* different things.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> add    ax, Records[bx+4]
> add    ax, Records[bx+6]
> add    ax, Records[bx+8]
> ```

> can I modify the program to **use a single instruction in a loop**

If you can live with writing a loop, then you'll have to accept that the loop comes with its overhead.
My reading of your sentence "use a single instruction" is that you want a single `ADD AX, ...` instruction performed in the loop.

Below is such a loop (same number of bytes [12]):

```
  mov si, 6
More:
  add ax, Records[bx+si+2]  ; First ..[bx+8] then ..[bx+6] then ..[bx+4]
  sub si, 2
  jnz More
```